# Validar o retorno da select PHP

Tags: php, select, if

estou fazendo uma select e antes de imprimir o formulario na tela gostaria de validar se a select retornou linhas, como faço isso ja tentei de varias formas sem sucesso.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($fat_ped_online_vende);
$stmt->execute();
```

Queria fazer algo tipo

```
if(se retornar linhas):
    //entra aqui
endif;
```

Comment: Qual é o seu banco de dados ?

Answer (score 5):

Você pode fazer assim

```
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
if(count($result) > 0){
  ...
}
```

Comment: No meu codigo tenho  foreach ($stmt->fetchall()as $key =>  $row):

Comment: Quando faco isso ele deixa de funcionar

Comment: É só você alterar o `$stmt->fetchall()` que está no `foreach` pela variável `$result`.

Answer (score 2):

Com [rowCount()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.rowcount.php) do [PDOStatement](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.pdostatement.php):

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($fat_ped_online_vende);
$stmt->execute();
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) // verificar se a SQL trouxe linhas
{
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(); // resultado    
}
```

<sup>***Observação:*** pode acontecer que em alguns bancos isso não tenha o efeito esperado mediante texto na própria [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.rowcount.php): "*However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications*" em ***pt-BR***: "*No entanto, esse comportamento não é garantido para todos os bancos de dados e não deve ser invocado para aplicativos portáteis*".</sup>

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [PDOStatement](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.pdostatement.php)
- [PDOStatement::rowCount](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

Comment: Esta retornando zero

Comment: if($stmt->rowCount() == 0):

Comment: vai depender da SQL @MaiconFernandoStefenedaSil, tem resultados? qual é a SQL:

Comment: Também pode ser por que o `$stmt->rowCount()` não funciona em qualquer database para contar o retorno de um `SELECT`.

Comment: @Augusto eu nunca ouvi falar nisso, em nenhum lugar, se por acaso tem uma referencia disso ???

Comment: No próprio link que você postou tem na descrição, http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Comment: Bom @Augusto eu comentei pedindo o banco que ele utiliza, acredito que são poucos bancos que não tem o resultado esperado, vamos aguardar o que ele diz!